# MySQL - Left and Self Join in single query

Tags: mysql, sql

As the title states I am trying to Left Join information from table B, but then also show matching information in table A, thats not associated in table B. Below is my query but it's currently only returning the inner join.

```
SELECT 
    concat(u.firstname, ' ', u.lastname) AS clientName,
    u.email AS clientEmail, 
    u.created_at AS signedUp,
    u.refferedby AS referredBy,
    concat(t.firstname, ' ', t.lastname) AS trainerWho,
    t.email AS trainerWhoEmail,
    concat(usr.firstname, ' ', usr.lastname) AS clientWho,
    usr.email as clientWhoEmail
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN trainers t ON u.externalid = t.hashId
    INNER JOIN users usr ON u.externalid = usr.hashId
WHERE u.refferedby IS NOT NULL
    AND DATE(u.created_at) >= CURDATE() -7
    ORDER BY(u.created_at);
```

Comment: That's what is supposed to do, since the inner join returns matching records only. Perhaps you should change your inner join to left join as well. Pls explain using sample data what the current query returns and what you would expect it to return.

Comment: Left join fixed it! I'm pretty new to MySQL queries and didn't realize you can use multiple of the same JOIN other than INNER. I appreciate the response. I was expecting results where both the trainers and users table returned results matching the ids, but only the inner join results were returned, which was one record. With both as LEFT JOIN I am getting 8 records returned, which is what was expected.

Comment: Nope, there is no limitation on the number of the same joins you can apply from any join type. (There are overall limitations on queries, but these are beyond this topic to discuss)